# Get Integer from end of URL - Pass into RedBean

Tags: javascript, php, redbean

I have a table and when I click to view a specific row in more detail I am taken to a page with the following URL:

webproject/projects/1

- with 1 been the ID of the row that I selected on the previous page.

In my PDP i want to obtain this value and run it into a RedBean call as follows:

```
public function projects()
        {
            return R::findAll('projects', 'themeid = [id from URL]');
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your id into a variable `$url_id` you should change a little your code:

```
return R::findAll('projects', 'themeid = ?', [$url_id]);
```

or

```
return R::findAll('projects', 'themeid = :id', [':id' => $url_id]);
```

so, what you need in this case is replace your values with `?` signal and on the third parameter pass an array with values.

Remember, the number of `?` must be the same of array length